# Python convert json file to html

Tags: json, pandas

I have a bunch of Pandas data frames. I want to view them in HTML (and also want the json). So, this is what I did:

1. masterDF = concatenated all dfs  (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, ..])
2. masterDf.to_json(jsonFile, orient = 'records')  => this gives a valid json file, but, in a list format.
3. htmlStr = json2html.convert(json = jsonString)
4. htmlFile = write htmlStr to a myFile.html.

The json file looks like this:
[{"A":1458000000000,"B":300,"C":1,"sid":101,"D":323.4775570025,"score":0.0726},{"A":1458604800000,"B":6767,"C":1,"sid":101,"D":321.8098393263,"score":0.9524},{"A":1458345600000,"B":9999,"C":3,"sid":29987,"D":125.6096891766,"score":0.9874},{"A":1457827200000,"B":3110,"C":2,"sid":787623,"D":3010.9544668798,"score":0.0318}]

Problem I am facing:
   pd.to_json outputs a jsonfile with [] format. Like a list. I am unable to use this json file to load. Like this:

```
with open(jsonFile) as json_data:
   js = json.load(json_data)
   htmlStr = json2html.convert(json = js)
   return htmlStr
```

Is there a way to load a json-file like the above and convert to html?

Comment: why dont you just export in csv and use the good ol excel to see your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use pandas.DataFrame.to_html? (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)

Comment: I really need json file as an intermediate output. Have to store that somewhere.

Comment: but what prevents you from doing both? masterDF.to_json and then masterDF.to_html for visualisation?

Comment: Actually...nothing prevents me. I chose your option to generate html and json directly from masterDf. Did not think of it before!!